# How do I do multiple mongoose aggregate search?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a structure like below in MongoDB:

```
{
    memberId: 1236,
    platform: "PC",
    channel: "A",
    page: "B",
    ip: "192.168.10.1",
    isActive: true,
    createOn: "2017-02-19T09:28:43.688Z",
    isSubmit: false,
}
```

Now I need to do aggregate search as follows:

```
{

    memberId: 1236,
    platform: "PC",
    channel: "A",
    page: "B",
    pv: 111,
    uv: 10
}
```

`uv` (user views) is just based on `pv` (page views) distinct by `ip`.

How do I do multiple aggregate search?

I can only get one, either `pv` or `uv`, but can't get them all at the same time.

I use mongoose in node.js

Answer (score 1):

You need first to identify what is your grouping `_id`. You can identify a single page with unique couple values of `memberId`,`platform`,`channel` and `page`, `$sum` all document count per `$ip` and add another `$group` to count distinct IP and `$sum` per page :

```
Data.aggregate([{
    $group: {
        _id: {
            memberId: "$memberId",
            platform: "$platform",
            channel: "$channel",
            page: "$page",
            ip: "$ip"
        },
        pv: {
            $sum: 1
        }
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: {
            memberId: "$_id.memberId",
            platform: "$_id.platform",
            channel: "$_id.channel",
            page: "$_id.page"
        },
        pv: {
            $sum: "$pv"
        },
        uv: {
            $sum: 1
        }
    }
}], function(err, res) {
    if (err)
        console.log(err);
    else
        console.log(res);)
})
```

You can find sample output/output [here](https://gist.github.com/bertrandmartel/333635227172ab732b8c6ff2f230f162)

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I already solved this problem with your help.
At the beginning I also tried to use two or more $group, but my logic is not correct so I can't work it out.

Comment: You're welcomed, you can accept the answer if it's Ok